# Why can I not render a displacement map animation?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation, displacement

I've followed a Gleb Alexandrov tutorial (2.77) [up to this point](https://youtu.be/gBWaARrOiyE?t=326), using Blender 2.82. However, I can't seem to get Cycles to render the required displacement maps. Can anybody tell me how to get over this hump?

You should be able to download my .blend [here!](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AggYP6QsQK1_jEwfD07JquQmQ_nl?e=3mypB8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baked the dynamics of the canvas, switched renderer to Eevee and it worked fine. =/